# How to catch spinning ladda buttons at the moment?

Tags: javascript, ladda

I use [ladda.js](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) in different parts of my page as following:

```
var siteVisitConfirmation = $('.btn-site-visit-confirmation').ladda();

siteVisitConfirmation.click(function(position) {
    siteVisitConfirmation.ladda("start");
    setSiteVisitLocation(position);
});
```

I have 5 ladda buttons like this. Is there any way to find out which `laddaButtons` are spinning?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if a single button is spinnig, you can use the native function of the library called `isLoading()`:

```
let laddaButton = $('#mybutton').ladda();
laddaButton.ladda('start');
laddaButton.isLoading(); //true
```

But if you need to get multiple, then you could simple check if the button has the `data-loading` attribute:

```
let allButtonsSpinning = $('.btn-site-visit-confirmation[data-loading]');
```

[Source](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda/blob/master/js/ladda.js)